# How to get $\int_{\partial B_r}\partial _r u(y)dy=\int_{\partial B_r}u\cdot \nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have that $$\int_{\partial B_1}\int_0^R \partial_r u(r\sigma )drd\sigma =\int_0^R \int_{\partial B_1} \partial _r u(r\sigma )d\sigma dr=\int_0^R\int_{\partial B_r}\partial _ru(y)d\sigma dr,$$

but normally a surface integral must be of the form $$\int_{\partial \Omega }u\cdot \nu$$
where $\nu$ is the unit exterior normale. Here, I suppose that $$\partial _r u(y)=\nabla u\cdot \nu,$$
but it's ambiguous how I get it concretely. And what would be $\nu$ ? something as $r\boldsymbol v$ for a vector $\boldsymbol v$ ?   Any explanation ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your bounty. How do you interpret $\sigma $ if it's not the normal vector of $\partial B_1$ . An thus a direct calculation gives $\partial _r u(r\sigma )=\nabla u\cdot \sigma $

Answer (score 0):

I will do an answer even if I don't understand very much your bounty (and also not your question to be honest). You set $$B_R=\{r\sigma \mid r\in [0,R]\},$$
where $\sigma $ is the vector field that parametrize $\partial B_1$. In particular, it's length is $1$ and it's normal to $\partial B_1$. For example, for the unit disk of $\mathbb R^2$, you have that $$\sigma =(\cos\theta , \sin \theta ),$$
or for the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^3$ $$\sigma =(\cos \theta \sin\varphi, \sin\theta \sin\varphi,\cos\varphi),\quad \varphi\in [0,\pi],\theta \in [0,2\pi].$$
Using the chain rules gives $$\partial _ru(r\sigma )=\nabla u\cdot \sigma,$$ 
and thus $$\int_{\partial B_R}\partial _r u(y)dy=\int_{\partial B_R}\nabla u\cdot \sigma,$$
and $\sigma $ is the unit normal vector to $B_1$, and thus, also to $B_R$. I hope this answer to your question...

Comment: Ouuppss, yes indeed, you right. I don't know why I block on this. Thank you anyway.